# Sum of folder sizes smaller than used disk space

Tags: windows

In Windows 10 on "Properties" of disk C: i see that nearly all the space is used (237GB). When i select all folders in C: and look at "Proberties" a size of about 80GB is shown (show hidden files is enabled).

the command

```
wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption
```

shows

```
Caption  FreeSpace      Size
C:       9962520576     254974554112
```

...meaning that the disk is nearly full.

Like this, i can't tell what data is taking the space. How can i find it out?

Answer (score 1):

Show Hidden Files will not show files and folders such as hiberfil.sys, pagefile.sys, and System Volume Information.

The system could have restore points or saved previous Windows installations.

One quick way to check this would be to run the commands from an elevated command prompt:

```
cleanmgr.exe /verylowdisk  

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup /resetbase
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers measure different things. File *size* is the data in the file, *disk usage* is what the files use on the disk (need to add directories, unused tails after the file's data, other overhead -- the structures telling where on disk the file's pieces reside, file owner, permissions, and so on).